# Translating Fractions

Tags: traducción, números

Para hacer una receta necesito escribir las ingredientes.

> Un ingrediente son **3/4ths** cup of white rice.

¿Comó traducir las fracciones en español?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Las fracciones se traducen de acuerdo al uso de los números ordinales. Para 1/2 decimos *un medio*, 1/3 = un tercio.
Usamos el entero (excepto con el número 1, que se dice *un* y no *uno*) en el numerador y *medio* o *tercio* en el denominador.

Si deseamos avanzar desde el 4 en adelante, como 3/4, usamos el número *ordinal* en el denominador, esto es *1/4 = un cuarto*.

Esto implica entonces que 3/4 corresponden a *tres cuartos.* Por ejemplo: *agregue 3/4 de una taza de arroz = agregue **tres cuartos** de una taza de arroz.*

Comment: Cómo se escribe 5/6th y 7/8ths?

Comment: *cinco sextos* y *siete octavos*, respectivamente.